# My question has been asked but not answered at all. What should I do?

Tags: discussion

My problem is somewhat similar to [My question has already been asked, but not really answered? What should I do?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1862/99468).
But in my case the question has not been answered at all.

My first idea was to write a comment below the question. But you need 50 reputation for that and I just created this MO-account. So one option would be to wait  till I get enough reputation, but that can take a while.
Another option is to create a new question and link it with the old one. And the last option is not to ask at all.

The question I want to ask has been asked here: [On the proof by Chu-Kobayashi that transformation groups are Lie groups](https://mathoverflow.net/q/233870/99468).
It is really detailed and contains everything I want to know. So the best thing for me would be to "activate" this old quesion. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can bump a question to the top of the list by editing it (respectively, suggesting an edit and wait for approval), by posting an answer or by offering a bounty. Adding a comment won't bump a post. Without points, I think your only option to bump unconditionally is by posting an answer. (In principle you could delete the answer afterwards, but this is of course not good style.).

Comment: Also keep in mind: not every question is answered.   Or even answerable.

Comment: Probably this MO meta post will garner more attention for the MO post. I expect there are experts in the MO community who would be able to answer the MO question.

Comment: @Gerald Edgar: That is true in general. But in this particular case the question is "just" about understanding the details of an existing proof so I think there is an answer. There is  a lot of interest in this question so maybe the answer isn't that easy though.